# How to debug the Calling Controller Using ngrok tool or any other tool?

Tags: botframework

I am working on bot framework technology, Today I am working skype calling feature for that I followed below link.
https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/calling.html

After I added the entire code then build and publish my application into azure, then now I am starting to test my application using ngrok tool but it always generates “400 bad request”.

I configured all things are correctly.

I already seen in the above documentation to test application using Ngrok tool but its not working.

Please tell me how to debug the Calling Controller using ngrok tool or any other tool.

-Pradeep

Answer (score -1):

Some common errors.

When debugging locally:

- Your bot’s endpoint is incorrect. Make sure you have included the
  path at the end of the URL (e.g. /api/messages).
- The bot is
  configured with an App ID or an App Password, when both fields should
  be blank.
- The Emulator is configured with an App ID or an App
  Passoword, when both fields sholud be blank.

When debugging in the cloud:

- Your bot’s endpoint is incorrect. See Step 1, above.
- The bot is configured without a Microsoft App Id or a Microsoft App
  Password.
- Your Microsoft App Id or Microsoft App Password are incorrect.

This [link](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/support/troubleshooting-bot-framework-authentication/#navtitle) provides some additional tips on using ngrok and resolving auth issues